# how to set max date to current date and hide all upcoming and past dates in datepicker

Tags: jsp, datepicker

//    this is my code of date picker formed using date-picker.css class 
so kindly clarify my doubt that how to set max date to current date and hide all upcoming and past date picker

```
      <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding-right bigger-110" style="margin-left:-1px;margin-top:18px;margin-left:81px">Date of Birth</div>
               <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-top:18px;margin-left:-3px;">
                  <div class="input-group" style="margin-left:-92px">
          <input type="text" class="date-picker form-control input-sm bigger-110" placeholder="DD-MMM-YYYY" id="datepickerdob" name="datepickerdob" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy" onclick="dob1()"/>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon left">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: what does `ob1()` has in it ? add that as well in your question.

Comment: ob1() is iam setting the max value by jquey as   function dob1() {
                $('#datepickerdob').datepicker({
                    minDate: 0,
                    maxDate: new Date();
                });
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an typo near `new Date();` here `;`  removed that .Also ,you can call your `datepicker` onload of your page instead of calling it by function.

**Demo Code**:

```js
//onload of page this will get called
$(function() {
  $('#datepickerdob').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: new Date()
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 no-padding-right bigger-110" style="margin-left:-1px;margin-top:18px;">Date of Birth</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-top:18px;margin-left:-3px;">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="date-picker form-control input-sm bigger-110" placeholder="DD-MMM-YYYY" id="datepickerdob" name="datepickerdob" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy"  />
    <span class="input-group-addon left">
 <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```